# How do I filter an Access report/query based on values from a related table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I think this is probably pretty basic but I haven't been able to figure this out.

I have created an Access database for student information. I have a "Students" table, and a "School Years" table.  The "Students" table includes a lookup field to the "School Years" table allowing to select each year the student attended school. The "School Years" table includes a list of years, along with a YN field called "Current Year" to specify which year is considered current.

My intention is that reports/queries be configured to only show "Current Year" students.  How do I filter my reports based on when Students.[School Year] includes Year where [School Years].Current = True?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing `School Year` as numeric field having year value, you can try this:

```
select * from [Students] where [School Year] = year(date());
```

- `date()` - returns current date
- `year(date)` - returns year of the given date

Comment: Thanks, Gurwinder. The problem with school years is that they roll-over in the middle of a calendar year, so just checking against the current date doesn't really work.  I like the automation, but in this case it's actually more practical for me to be able to specify the "Current" school year.  I have the year as a text field, with data "2016-2017", "2017-2018"... which is proving more challenging than I'd anticipated.